# Get file modified date in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io, last-modified

I have a number of files in a folder, and I need to get the last modified date. So I used

```
FDate = IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(FName)
```

It works fine with some files, but on others, I get a date of 1/1/1601. But when I check the files in Windows Explorer, all the dates look normal (recent). So, I'm guessing there are multiple file dates stored in the file system, and the ones .NET is seeing are not the ones Windows is seeing. How can I get exactly the date which appears as "date modified" in a file explorer window?

I tried some [Visual Basic 6.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Timeline) API stuff, but that doesn't seem to work in .NET.

Answer (score 36):

From [File.GetLastWriteTime Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx):

> If the file described in the path parameter does not exist, this method returns 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

The file you are querying is probably missing.

Comment: I can't believe it, you right, it isn't!! But it was earlier!! Something else wierd is happening. Funny how when you get stuck in a problem you can sometimes miss the obvious. Cheers

Answer (score 7):

The query mentioned below will get the correct `LastModifiedDate` for all of the files contained in a folder.

```
    Dim strFilepath = ""  'Specify path details
    Dim directory As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(strFilepath)
    Dim File As System.IO.FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles()
    Dim File1 As System.IO.FileInfo
    For Each File1 In File
        Dim strLastModified As String
        strLastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(strFilepath & "\" & File1.Name).ToShortDateString()
    Next
```