# Extracting files from a Flash Drive Error

Tags: vb.net

Hey I am trying to work with the EnumerateFiles function, but when I try and run my program it says: ***error BC30616: Variables 'e' hides a variable in an enclosing block***

Could anyone help? its much appreciated!

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmExtractionator

    Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

        Dim sourceDirectory As String = "F:\CopierFolderforTestDriveCapstone"
        Dim archiveDirectory As String = "F:\FilesExtracted"

        Try
            Dim txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory)

            If(Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(archiveDirectory )) Then
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(archiveDirectory)
            End If

            For Each currentFile As String In txtFiles
                Dim fileName = currentFile.Substring(sourceDirectory.Length + 1)
                File.Move(currentFile, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName))
            Next
        Catch eT As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(eT.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this Change**

**reason Variable : e is used twice**

```
Catch eT As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(eT .Message)
End Try
```

**Where is *e* already used ?**

> btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal **e** As
>   System.EventArgs)

**update:**
About your Doubt:

```
 Directory.Move(currentFile, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName))
```

i think you are trying to move file not Directory right?

use     `File.Move`  instead , remember to create the `archiveDirectory`

**update2:**
Add this to your code before `For Each`

```
If(Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(archiveDirectory )) Then
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(archiveDirectory )
End If
```

Comment: Hey thank you you were right! Just wondering though, every time I hit the button to extract the files and put them in a new folder it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes I am new lol, but I will accept your answer.  I am really trying to move files inside of a folder if I am doing it right

Comment: use File.Move?, remember to create the archiveDirectory

Comment: I was thinking that It would create a folder for me and put the files inside of it, but you are saying I need to already have that folder created inside the flash drive? and I am attempting to use the File.Move (I do appreciate your help very much)

Comment: it say 'If' must end with endIf should I add it in there?

Comment: Okay I tired it, and its not working. I think I messed it all up.
Heres what I got...I edited my question..

Comment: waht u mean by "not working", is it not copying? and any exceptions ? then what exception?

Comment: Its says the following:
Could not find a part of the path 'F:\CopierFolderforTestDriveCapstone'.

Comment: hey does F:\CopierFolderforTestDriveCapstone actually exists and it contain files? its your source?then go find F:\CopierFolderforTestDriveCapstone it!

Comment: Wait wait, I was wrong I had the folder name wrong in my flash drive, it was successful! Thank you very much man.  Now all I need to do is find how I can copy only the recently modified files.

Comment: have some reference around http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668340/get-file-modified-date-in-vb-net